# How to compare and filter rows in SQL by various columns

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following structure and content:
[image: A table]

As you can see, there can be the same FQDN and NAME, however, TIMESTAMP is always different.
I have been trying to get rid of the old records in order to leave only the newest ones:
[image]
Could you please advise if there is a way for we to reach my goal?
Here is the SQL query I have got so far:

```
SELECT devices.fqdn, ports.pid, ports.name, ports.`status`, `subStatus`.`substatus`, updateLog.previousValue, updateLog.newValue, `updateLog`.`user`, `updateLog`.`timestamp`, `user`.`email`
FROM `updateLog`
LEFT JOIN `user` ON user.id = updateLog.user 
LEFT JOIN ports ON updateLog.rowId=ports.pid
LEFT JOIN subStatus ON ports.subStatus=subStatus.id
LEFT JOIN slots ON ports.slot=slots.sid
LEFT JOIN devices ON slots.device=devices.did 
WHERE (updateLog.rowId IN (select pid from ports where status=2)) 
AND (updateLog.columnName = 'status' AND updateLog.tableName = 'ports' and updateLog.newValue=2) 
ORDER BY ports.pid asc LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: You can simply add a condition in `WHERE` clause, like: `AND timestamp > 1666000000`

Comment: It might be a temp solution, however, the issue may re-appear again in the future, so I'm looking for a more long term solution

Comment: are you trying to delete old rows?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS in order to only get answers that work for you.

Comment: E.g. Postgresql has `DISTINCT ON`, which would be handy here.

Answer (score 1):

To get the top row(s) per group is usually solved with window functions (either `MAX OVER` here, `ROW_NUMBER`, `RANK` or `DENSE_RANK`).

Here is the query with `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    d.fqdn,
    p.pid, p.name, p.status,
    ss.substatus,
    ul.previousvalue, ul.newvalue, ul.user, ul.timestamp,
    user.email,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.fqdn, p.name ORDER BY ul.timestamp DESC) AS rn
  FROM updatelog ul
  LEFT JOIN ports p ON ul.rowId = p.pid
  LEFT JOIN substatus ss ON p.ss = ss.id
  LEFT JOIN slots s ON p.slot = s.sid
  LEFT JOIN devices d ON s.device = d.did 
  WHERE ul.rowId IN (SELECT pid FROM ports WHERE status = 2)
  AND ul.columnname = 'status'
  AND ul.tablename = 'p'
  AND ul.newvalue = 2 
) ranked
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT timestamp FROM table
LEFT JOIN SELECT other rows

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment.
However, SELECT DISTINCT will not solve the issue, as the timestamp column is pretty unique already, the main problem is FQDN and NAME being repeated at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

To get the latest timestamp from each (fqdn and name):

```
SELECT fqdn, name, MAX(Timestamp)
FROM tableName
GROUP BY fqdn, name
```

If you need to return other fields:

```
SELECT t1.fqdn, t1.name, t1.user, t1.Timestamp
FROM tableName t1
WHERE timestamp = (
    SELECT MAX(timestamp)
    FROM tableName t2 WHERE t1.fqdn = s2.fqdn AND t1.name = t2.name
)
```

Comment: Let me try to fit it into my code, as there is already a WHERE statement there.